# How does kafka handle adding partitions to a compacted topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I was searching for a documentation how kafka handles adding partitions to a compacted topic.
As per my understanding this would break the compaction as default partitioner sending messages to partition key%num_partitions leading to a different distribution of keys making the compaction impossible.

Is there a "legal" way to increase the partitions for a compacted topic?

Comment: It'll handle it the same way as a regular topic. Yes, it breaks compaction for newer data. The only workaround is to mirror data to a newer, larger topic and start producing there

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's all I wanted to know!